what is the title of the story that includes a character named Glauken and a woman named Magda?
Glauken is a man who is fated to battle a monster which has the ability to slow down earth's rotation to nothing, or at least to make darkness last longer every day until there is no more daylight. At the beginning of the tale he is an old man living with his wife Magda, and his desire is to be allowed to finish his life in a natural manner. Unfortunately for him, the monster, for lack of a better word, appears once more, and he is transformed into a vigorous, red-haired man of thirty years or so, strapping on his sword as he heads out to do battle with his adversary, and tormented by the knowledge that Magda will hate him for becoming young again, as has wife after wife over the many years of his existence.

This is a novel not a short story. It's Nightworld, which is the sixth book in F. Paul Wilson's Adversary series.

The end of the world begins at dawn, when the sun rises later than it should. Then the holes appear. The first forms in Central Park, within sight of an apartment where Repairman Jack and a man as old as time watch with growing dread. Gaping holes, bottomless and empty... until sundown, when the first hungry, unearthly creatures appear.
"Nightworld" brings F. Paul Wilson's Adversary Cycle and Repairman Jack saga to an apocalyptic finale as Jack and Glaeken search the Secret History to gather a ragtag army for a last stand against the Otherness and a hideously transformed Rasalom.

The man is Glaeken not Glauken, but his wife is called Magda.
Glaeken at first refuses to take up the sword, but eventualy he takes it and there is a huge burst if light as he is transformed. The book describes the scene afterwards:

Carol saw a smoldering hole where the light had burst through. She approached it cautiously and looked down into the living room below, afraid of what she might see there, afraid that Glaeken had been harmed somehow by the blaze of light.
But no charred, blackened remains lay crumbled on the rug below. No Glaeken either. Instead, a stranger stood in his place—in Glaeken’s clothes—clutching the hilt that sat upon the blade.
“Look!” Carol whispered. “Who’s that?”
He was taller than Glaeken. He had the old man’s broad build but was much younger, perhaps Jack’s age. And fiery red hair. His shoulders and upper arms stretched the seams of the shirt he wore. Who—?
And then she caught a glimpse of his blue eyes and knew beyond all question—
“It’s Glaeken!”
She felt an arm slip around her shoulder as she heard Bill’s hoarse whisper beside her.
“But he’s so young! He can’t be more than thirty-five!”


Thank you for answering my question so promptly. I was thinking it was a novel, remembering a hard cover, but I was having trouble posting my question, so I just said to heck with it and called it a short story.  You're up late too, it seems. I appreciate your response!

@RichardTibbitts Hi Richard. If this is your story please click on the tick mark to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted.

Another wonderful answer!

@fez I spent most of my life reading trashy SF, and the rest of my life I wasted.
